# split matrix by row into single array

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, split, dataframe

I would like to split a matrix which has two columns into an array. Everything I have tested so far splits it by column, e.g.

```
mat <- rbind(c(5, 9),
             c(3, 7),
             c(2, 1),
             c(4, 3),
             c(8, 6))

ind <- gl(1,10)

>split(mat, ind)

[1] 5 3 2 4 8 9 7 1 3 6
```

But the desired output is:

```
5 9 3 7 2 1 4 3 8 6
```

There must be a super easy neat trick to do this. Any pointers are highly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `as.vector`:

```
## what you presently have
as.vector(mat) 
 [1] 5 3 2 4 8 9 7 1 3 6

## What you are looking for
as.vector(t(mat))
#  [1] 5 9 3 7 2 1 4 3 8 6
```